# Tax on Shipping only when Cart have taxable item

Tags: magento-2.1.7, shipping-tax

I want to configure the tax on shipping only when the cart has any taxable product.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check: https://coolblueweb.com/blog/configuring-shipping-taxes-in-magento/

Comment: @NikunjVadariya it works for all either I have a taxable item or not. I want to add tax on shipping only when the cart has any of the taxable item.